# Postgres SQL How can I use group by and exclude the order by clause in it

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct, postgresql-9.5

I created a similar post and thought I had the answer but I didn't . What I would like to do is to get the nearest cities/towns given a certain latitudes and longitude while making the location column distinct . If you can see in my screenshot below the location of Orlando pops up twice, I would like to make that column distinct so that it can ignore the 2nd Orlando record . I am getting the nearest cities/towns correctly given the point of (28.458414,-81.395258)   . The issue is that I have many records for big cities that have different coordinates within the same city, if you see I have slightly different coordinates for the 2 Orlando records . Any suggestion would be great . I am using postgres 10

```
SELECT location,ABS(28.458414 - latitudes) + ABS(-81.395258-longitudes) as distance FROM zips 
 group by location,latitudes,longitudes
 ORDER BY distance asc limit 5
```

I have also done

```
SELECT distinct location, ABS(28.458414 - latitudes) + ABS(-81.395258-longitudes) as distance FROM zips 
 ORDER BY distance asc limit 5
```

This is being used to show users options of near by towns and it would look wrong to show 2 towns/cities twice .

[image]

Comment: Did you try `SELECT DISTINCT location` ?

Comment: Yes the order returned is slightly different but still returns Orlando twice since the distance is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure on what basis you want to ignore the second Orlando record. If there was an ID column indicating the order of rows, you could get the highest or least using `row_number()` or `DISTINCT ON`. Using `MIN` or `MAX` may be an option you could try, removing latitudes and longitudes from `group by`

```
SELECT location,MIN(distance) as distance
FROM
(
  SELECT location, ABS(28.458414 - latitudes) + ABS(-81.395258 -longitudes )
   as distance FROM zips 
 ) group by location
 ORDER BY distance asc limit 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit that was even better, thanks a lot